# Data Binding, Property Changed Event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a datagrid that contains 3 columns(text box column, combo box column,checkbox column), i would like to fire an event
when a value is selected in the combobox column, that will change the value of the check box column accordingly.

(i'm not expecting it to work the way the code is written , i simply don't know how to do it..)

for example in this code, when a grade lower than 90 is selected in the combo box column(which is bound to `Grade` property) i would like the value of the check box column( which is bound to `GoodStudent` property) to change to `false`, and when its higher than 90 , to change to `true`.

if possible without additional buttons.

Thanks.

ViewModel class :

```
 public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<int> Grades { get; set; }
    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }
    private int _Grade;
    public int Grade
    {
        get
        {
            return _Grade;
        }
        set
        {
            _Grade = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Grade"));
        }
    }
    private bool _GoodStudent;
    public bool GoodStudent
    {
        get
        {
            return _GoodStudent;
        }
        set
        {
            _GoodStudent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("GoodStudent"));
        }
    }
    public Student(string name, int g)
    {
        Grades = new ObservableCollection<int> { 30, 40, 90, 100 };
        this.Name = name;
        this.Grade = g;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}
class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>
        {
            new Student("Dan",80),
            new Student("Micheal",90)
        };
    }
}
```

XAML :

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Margin="69,50,47,66">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Names"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Grade, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Grades" Width="80">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Grades, Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding GoodStudent, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="IsGood" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Seems like you nearly have it (though you could use a DataTrigger instead of a calculated property), if you would make your check box binding correct (use the real property name) and set "GoodStudent" when grade was changed. What are we missing?

Comment: change `OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Grade"));` in goodStudent to `OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("GoodStudent"));`

Comment: thanks for your comments, i changed it now , but still it doesnt change the value of the `CheckBoxColumn`  when i insert to the `ComboBoxColumn` a grade that is higher than 90 , i want the value of the CheckBoxColumn to be set to `true` automatically when its higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and Dirty solution:

I highly recommend you, to move `Grades` out of `Student` and put it into your ViewModel instead

**Model:**

```
public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<int> Grades { get; set; }
        private string _Name;
        public string Name {
            get {
                return _Name;
            }
            set {
                _Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
            }
        }
        private int _Grade;
        public int Grade {
            get {
                return _Grade;
            }
            set {
                _Grade = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Grade"));
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("GoodStudent"));
            }
        }
        private bool _GoodStudent;
        public bool GoodStudent {
            get { return this.Grade >= 90; }
        }
        public Student(string name, int g)
        {
            Grades = new ObservableCollection<int> { 30, 40, 90, 100 };
            this.Name = name;
            this.Grade = g;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Xaml:**

```
<Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Margin="69,50,47,66">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Names"/>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Grade}" Header="Grades" Width="80">
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Grades, Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding GoodStudent , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" Header="IsGood" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks! it works great ! and i see your point about moving grades out of Student class thanks alot !